# columns don't align even with the same content

Tags: html, css

I'm still very new to using HTML and CSS. I have 2 divs to make columns. I have no idea why they don't seem to align? The other column appears to be longer than the other despite having the same number of items. Does it have something to do with the flex?

Here is a snippet. It's still very messy when shown on a small screen so please view it full page.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.other-tracks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.track-row {
  margin: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.small-gray {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.album-title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: -25px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.album-img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.a {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.list {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: solid 1px #999;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.item-gray {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.track-title {
  color: #f0e567;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <section class="other-tracks">
    <div class="track-row">
      <h6 class="small-gray">EP</h6>
      <h5 class="album-title">Fuyunohanashi</h5>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JqFj5Jd.png" class="album-img" alt="Fuyunohanashi">
      <h6 class="small-gray">2019</h6>
      <ul class="a">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">まるつけ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">FUYUNOHANASHI</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">3:52</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">冬のはなし</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">FUYUNOHANASHI</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">3:26</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">Marutsuke - Instrumental</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">FUYUNOHANASHI</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">3:50</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">Fuyunohanashi - Instrumental</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">FUYUNOHANASHI</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">3:26</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="track-row">
      <h6 class="small-gray">Singles</h6>
      <h5 class="album-title">夜が明ける</h5>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jhyARrw.jpg" class="album-img" alt="Singles">
      <h6 class="small-gray">2020</h6>
      <ul class="a">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">夜が明ける</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">夜が明ける</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">4:41</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">へたくそ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">へたくそ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">3:06</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">ステージから君に捧ぐ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">ステージから君に捧ぐ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">4:18</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">まるつけ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">まるつけ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">3:52</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you have the two different scripts in the same row, although you have set the font-size equal for both, their line heights don't seem to be equal. I guess that's because the scripts are so different in terms of 'descenders' (how much they go below the baseline), but that is just a guess.

So set the line-height explicitly wherever you set the font-size.

I have done that in this snippet but you will need to look to see whether you think it's enough or too much in each case.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.other-tracks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.track-row {
  margin: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.small-gray {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #999;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.album-title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: -25px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.album-img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.a {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.list {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: solid 1px #999;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.item-gray {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #999;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.track-title {
  color: #f0e567;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <section class="other-tracks">
    <div class="track-row">
      <h6 class="small-gray">EP</h6>
      <h5 class="album-title">Fuyunohanashi</h5>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JqFj5Jd.png" class="album-img" alt="Fuyunohanashi">
      <h6 class="small-gray">2019</h6>
      <ul class="a">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">まるつけ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">FUYUNOHANASHI</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">3:52</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">冬のはなし</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">FUYUNOHANASHI</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">3:26</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">Marutsuke - Instrumental</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">FUYUNOHANASHI</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">3:50</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">Fuyunohanashi - Instrumental</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">FUYUNOHANASHI</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">3:26</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="track-row">
      <h6 class="small-gray">Singles</h6>
      <h5 class="album-title">夜が明ける</h5>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jhyARrw.jpg" class="album-img" alt="Singles">
      <h6 class="small-gray">2020</h6>
      <ul class="a">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">夜が明ける</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">夜が明ける</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">4:41</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">へたくそ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">へたくそ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">3:06</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">ステージから君に捧ぐ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">ステージから君に捧ぐ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">4:18</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <p class="track-title">まるつけ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">まるつけ</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p class="item-gray">3:52</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for each sections to be balance, you can always set a `min-height` property to each of your `.list` class to have equal heights.

You can do it in a CSS like this simply:

```
.list { min-height:120px;} // set height whichever you want.
```